Error: Method not found: 'Void CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ISCRPropertyBag.AddLongLong(System.String, Int64)'
Al querer generar un reporte en Crystal Reports y exportarlo a PDF me arroja el siguiente error:
Method not found:
'Void CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.
ISCRPropertyBag.AddLongLong(System.String, Int64)'

Estoy usando la versión: 13.0.34.4636
Este es el código con el cual genero los reportes y no funciona:
public FileStreamResult CrearReporte()
{
    try
    {
        var Reporte = new ReportDocument();
        Reporte.FileName = Nombre_reporte;

        // agrega los parametros usados en el reporte
        if (ListaParametros.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= ListaParametros.Count - 1; x++)
            {
                Reporte.SetParameterValue(ListaParametros[x].NombreParametro, ListaParametros[x].ValorParamentro);
            }
        }

        // Configura las credenciales de la base de datos
        ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        connectionInfo.ServerName = this.Nombre_servidor;
        connectionInfo.DatabaseName = this.Nombre_db;
        connectionInfo.UserID = this.Nombre_usuario;
        connectionInfo.Password = this.Password_servidor;

        // Obtén la colección de tablas del informe y actualiza las credenciales para cada tabla
        TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        Tables tables = Reporte.Database.Tables;
        foreach (Table table in tables)
        {
            tableLogOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
            tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
            table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
        }

        Stream rptdoc = Reporte.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.NoFormat);
        Reporte.Close();
        Reporte.Dispose();
        return new FileStreamResult(rptdoc, "application/pdf");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
}

